# Meteor 1.4.4.1 issues running on AWS Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor

After upgrading to Meteor 1.4.1.1 I can run my Meteor app without issues locally, but once uploaded to AWS Beanstalk, I am getting the error below. Any help greatly appreciated. (Uninstalling/ReInstalling Meteor did no help). I am using meteor build --server-only ../build --architecture os.linux.x86_64 command to build on Windows if that matters and then deploying to AWS Linux instances.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'fibers'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/programs/server/boot.js:1:75)
at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.51-40.60.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v7.6.0-linux-
x64/bin/node" "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v7.6.0-linux-
x64/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v7.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

Comment: did you try `npm install` in your `build/server` directory ?

Comment: Tried it, no success.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I run npm install in the root folder of the project and it helped.